# PHP Curl is not loading

Tags: php, curl, php-7, ubuntu-16.04, php-curl

I have installed php curl. But still the curl module is not showing when I execute the command php -m.

OS version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
PHP version: PHP 7.0.7

Installed modules for curl:
curl, libcurl3, libcurl4-openssl-dev, php-curl, php7.0-curl

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: dll files are windows libraries. If you enable windows libraries on Ubuntu you will not <strike>go to space</strike> successfully enable cURL today.

Comment: Thanks DaveRandom. Could you please advice, if you see any way to fix this issue on linux?

Comment: you might have forgotten to restart apache/httpd.

Comment: I have restarted apache2 after installing curl libraries, but no use. I have restarted even the system also. But, still it does not load the curl module. :(

Comment: Try changing .dll to .so, verify that extension_dir points somewhere sensible and that the extension module file actually exists

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dave. The curl.so is available in the location /usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so and I enabled it in my php.ini and restarted the system. But, still php -m does not load curl module :(

Comment: Is you extension_dir directive pointed to that directory?

Comment: Yes Dave. extension_dir is pointing to the same directory.    extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20151012 => /usr/lib/php/20151012

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue with following steps:

Uninstalled php7.0-curl and curl by executing following commands:

```
sudo apt autoremove php7.0-curl
sudo apt autoremove curl
```

Then installed php-curl module again.

`sudo apt-get install php-curl`

Executed following commands to enable PHP 7.0 fpm

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
a2enconf php7.0-fpm
```

That's it. Now the curl module is loaded when checking "php -m" command. :)

Thanks.